# What is the file: syntax in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Today I've encountered the following line in an Docker image:

```
COPY file:e3123fcb6566efa979f945bfac1c94c854a559d7b82723e42118882a8ac4de66 in /usr/local/bin/
```

I've never seen this file:... syntax before.

Can someone explain this syntax? Thx.

Comment: SHA512 hash of the file(s).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823884/docker-image-layer-what-does-add-filesome-hash-in-mean