# What does map mean in a docker-file?

Tags: dockerfile

I came across this [EXPOSE command](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openremote/postgresql/latest/images/sha256-bf061ec51a0839e47be9791a4f87a824c8e50cccd759c3328d05c07db30b4464?context=explore):

```
EXPOSE map[5432/tcp:{} 8008/tcp:{} 8081/tcp:{}]
```

Can anyone please explain what the `map` syntax means?
And a link to the docs would be nice, I couldn't find it.

Comment: for me it's an invalid syntax, i get `ERROR: failed to solve: Invalid containerPort: {}` when trying it, i guess it's docker.io that is not displaying it correctly, see : https://github.com/openremote/postgresql/blob/main/Dockerfile , the real line is `EXPOSE 5432 8008 8081`

Comment: That's not standard Dockerfile syntax but an artifact of the way Docker Hub extracts data from an image.  [Docker image layer: What does `ADD file:<some_hash> in /` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823884/docker-image-layer-what-does-add-filesome-hash-in-mean) is similar.  I'd expect the Dockerfile to say something like `EXPOSE 5432 8008 8081` here.

Comment: Thanks. I also think, that it's just a display issue and that it is not in fact valid dockerfile syntax.